# Ternary function for Hamming distance, where '2' is wildcard

Tags: python, numpy, vector, similarity, hamming-distance

Let say I have the following array of vectors `x`, where the possible values are 0,1,2 :

```
 import numpy as np
 x = np.random.randint(0,3,(10,5), dtype=np.int8)
```

I want to do similarity match for all vectors with Hamming Distance zero or one, where the rules for matching are :

```
 1. 0 == 0 and 1 == 1 i.e. hamming distance is 0
 2. 2 match both 1 and 0 i.e. hamming distance is 0
 3. otherwise Hamming distance is 1
```

i.e. find some arithmetic operation that will return:

```
0 x 0 = 0
1 x 1 = 0
0 x 1 = 1
1 x 0 = 1
0 x 2 = 0
1 x 2 = 0
```

And my output should be the Hamming distance between each vector (row of) `x`, and arbitary vector `z`:

```
z = np.random.randint(0,2,5)
np.sum(np.add(x,z) == 1, axis=1)
```

Comment: match as true/false  , 2 stands for 0 and 1

Comment: sorry my mistake.. i meant it is hamming distance

Comment: @smci: No, read OP's notation.  The outcome of the `x` operation is the Hamming distance.  `0` is a match; `1` is a mismatch.

Comment: sten and Prune thanks for the clarifying edit

Comment: sten presumably you want to apply the Hamming distance to all N=10 vector rows xi, xj of the array x, right?  Then output the full NxN triangular matrix, right? Also I presume you want a (fast, vectorized) numpy answer, not base Python.

Comment: yes i posted the answer at the end

Comment: @sten: Sorry you're still not really listening to me. there's no such thing as the "Hamming distance" of a vector; only between two vectors. **You want to compute the HD between vector `z` and each row vector of your array `x`.** Your question never said that. If you simply provide an N x M array and ask to compute Hamming distance, we'd expect you want the full triangular matrix of HD between each vector and each other vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int(x+y == 1)
```

Is there something in this question I'm missing???

Comment: so far so good .. thanks .. let me see and test if i missed something else

Comment: How does that implement 2 matching both 1 and 0?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this do the trick?

```
((x!=y) ^ (x==2) ^ (y==2)).sum() <=1
```

Or if you want to allow two on either and both sides

```
((x!=y) ^ (x==2) | (y==2)).sum() <=1
```